# Ajax array to PHP equals null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax form, which at the end I have the values in an array. the code is below..but i keep getting null in my php response for these items. I think  I am doing this .ajax call wrong, any ideas would be greatly helpful. I also dont know what to write in the success section of the .ajax call. is that what I am missing? Please have a look below:

```
$('#submit_third').click(function(){
    //update progress bar
    $('#progress_text').html('100% Complete');
    $('#progress').css('width','339px');
    //prepare the fourth step

   var fields = new Array(
        $('#usernameReg').val(),
        $('#passwordReg').val(),
        $('#email').val(),
        $('#firstname').val(), 
        $('#lastname').val(),
        $('#city').val(),
        $('#phone').val(),
        categoryResult,
        $("#msg").val()                     
    );

    var tr = $('#fourth_step tr');
    tr.each(function(){
        //alert( fields[$(this).index()] )
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[$(this).index()]);
    });


    //slide steps
    $('#third_step').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#fourth_step').delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);          

    $('#submit_fourth').click(function(){
        //send information to server
        console.log(fields);
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: 'fields',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "php/postEngine.php",
            success: function(html){

            }
        });


    });     
});
```

php info (i am using flourish:

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../inc/init.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dev/form_data.php');
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dev/db_handling.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
try {

    $tbl_user   =   'tbl_users';

    $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $tbl_user 
        (username,
        email,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        city,
        phone)
        VALUES 
        (%s,
        %s,
        %s,
        %s,
        %s,
        %s
        )"
    );

    $db->query($statement,
        $un,
        $email,
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $city,
        $phone
        );

    //  Update of Email_Replied to 1

    //$db->execute("UPDATE accommodation SET Email_Replied = '1' WHERE ID = %i", $user_id); 

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $error_msg;
    echo $un;
    echo $email;
    echo $firstname;
    echo $lastname;
    echo $city;
    echo $phone;
    echo json_encode($un);
    $error_msg = 'An error occured on postEngine.php';

}
```

?>

```
$un         =   fRequest::get('fields[0]');
$email      =   fRequest::get('fields[2]');
$firstname  =   fRequest::get('fields[3]');
$lastname   =   fRequest::get('fields[4]');
$city       =   fRequest::get('fields[5]');
$phone      =   fRequest::get('fields[6]');
```

?>

Comment: Can we see your php code too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be :

```
data: fields,
```

not

```
data: 'fields',
```

right now all you're doing is sending the string 'fields' to the server, not the variable `fields` ?

Also make sure you're expecting an array on the server, and JSON back to the client etc. as you have specified JSON in the `dataType`, but in your success function you're calling it HTML, which it is not, not that it would matter as `html` is just a variable, but it does look like you're not expecting JSON, but still expecting JSON, and when the `dataType` is set to JSON, any response containing non valid JSON (like HTML) will fail ?

Comment: ill mark it correct, because you are. Nice, but I am getting undefined for values, how do I tell flourish (php un-framework) what the data type is?

Comment: I made this all a bit easier by using jquery $('#formID').serialize() of my form id for my data, created new vars from the form, and found serialize did all the parsing for me without problems of encoding. anyways, this is useful too . thanks again